# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString recognize webview content height

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios5

i placed a Uiwebview in a UIscrollview because after the uiwebview i want to display some images with the PageController.

i'm using this line of code.

```
   -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    if (webView!=WebView)return;
    float h;

    NSLog(@"web view is %f high", WebView.frame.size.height);
    NSString *heightString = [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"body\").offsetHeight;"];
    NSLog(@"web content is %@ high",heightString);

    h = [heightString floatValue] +12.0f;   
    WebView.frame = CGRectMake(WebView.frame.origin.x, WebView.frame.origin.y, WebView.frame.size.width, h);

    h = WebView.frame.origin.y + h + 20; 
    [ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, h)];


}
```

But `Web view is %f high` doesn't work, it does not reconize the height of the WebView does anyone know how i can fix this? Is this because i'm using `[WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`

And: `NSString *heightString = [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"body\").offsetHeight;"];`

```
 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /><style>body {  font: normal 13px helvetica; color: #565656;   } </style></head><body><p>%@</p></body></html> ",text];  


[WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *heightString = [Bericht stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];
```

Good luck,
Nathan

Comment: Hi..could you please help me on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793698/how-to-make-image-maps-clickable-using-uiwebview-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView already contains a scrollView, why are you adding it as a subview again. Check Apple's documentation [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/&ei=TSatT8XsD4PYrQfInOiyDA&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=AUyKo9oHaYJQCKgPbU_-Jw)

Comment: Because he want's to display (UIPageControl) images under his UIWebview?