# How to make image maps clickable using UIWebview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, uiimageview

I am looking how to get 'one' and 'park' string value (which is image_map coordinates clickable spot on UIwebview's) onclick from HTML to iPHone native obj-c.
I have put the code to get string value but it is not responding...plz check and help

I have updated code with **possible answer**. Which will be complicated if the image maps and map clickable surfaces are more. Any help and suggestion with coding and explaination on this are appreciated. thanks in advance

**Updated:**
**For HTML code**

```
<html>
<body onload="anyFunction();">
<script language="javascript">

function anyFunction(){
window.location='value';
}

function callFromActivity(msg){
document.getElementById("circle").innerHTML = 'onclick';
    }
</script> 

 <img src="map_new123.png" width="1500" height="731" border="0" usemap="#map" />
 <a href="didTap://button1">
<map name="map">
     //want ot get below onclick values one and park in to objective c .....
<area shape="circle" coords="1047,262,26" onclick="one" />
<area shape="circle" coords="1118,590,24" onclick="park" />
</a></map>
```

**For Obj-c**

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didTap://button1"]) {
  //        
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connectivity!" message:@" Hello" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [myAlert show];

//the below line of code should get the string but its not working

 NSString* html = [myWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('circle').onclick"]; 

    return NO;
}
return YES; }
```

**Possible answer**

```
//Html coding
<area  shape="circle" coords="1047,262,26" onclick="one" href="didTap://button1" value="one" />
<area  shape="circle" coords="1118,590,24" onclick="park" href="didTap://button2"  value="park"/>


  //Obj C

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didTap://button1"]) {
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected  Location!"  message:@"One" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"GetDirection"  otherButtonTitles:@"Quit",nil] autorelease];
    [myAlert show];

    return NO;
 }
 if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didTap://button2"]) 
 {
     UIAlertView *myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected  Location!"  message:@"Park" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"GetDirection"  otherButtonTitles:@"Quit",nil] autorelease];
     [myAlert show];
     return NO;
 }
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "fetch from HTML". The most likely solution will be to use `UIWebView` javascript method: `-(NSString*)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

If you want to get the `innerHTML` from the tag with id  'test':

```
NSString *innerHTML = [aWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('test').innerHTML"];
```

Comment: If you look my HTML code....I want to fetch 'one' and 'park' string in my native iPhone obj-c method(textfield).

Comment: your code is correct for obj-c. But what should I put in to HTML for the same??

Comment: why not simply remove the a href and then add it to the specific areas and call different URLs? `didTap://button1/one` you could then check for the scheme to handle the url in the webview's delegate. Check the host `button1` if you need and then check the path.

Comment: I have updated my question with possible answer which will be complicated if the image maps/clickable area are more. Can you suggest or update your answer according to good practice/logic with better explanation with coding..